# How can I set a Landbot variable from the Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, chatbot

I am building a Landbot, and so far I can pass in user input; however, I need to return an output back into a Landbot variable so I can print it back on the screen.

I found some [documentation](https://help.landbot.io/article/9kt26mmub4-landbot-variables-javascript-variables) that said to use this:

```
Landbot.exec('landbot-custom-data',{answertoquestion:answer});
```

However, for some odd reason, I need to add a button after that javascript code so the variable can be accessible in the Landbot scope.

I have reached out to Landbot support, but they only told me that I must always add a button to access a javascript variable. So, they weren't able to produce a reason *why*, but they simply reiterated my original question.

Is there any way I can bypass that button step?

Thanks in advance!

(EDIT: added additional information to explain my step process.)

Comment: It is very important to understand that this step (Javascript to Landbot) it ALWAYS needs an input of the visitor, before the Javascript value is available in the Landbot variable.

Comment: Do you know why that is the case, though? It seems so arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to bypass the button step. It works if you use a variable that has been used before. So if in the before process you can define variables you won't be needing later on you can overwrite their values. In this case it works without the button.